# Inventory Macro / Conditional Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm taking on a project in which I've built a map of locations in which house inventory. On one sheet is the map and on another sheet would be inventory that hasnt moved in **X** number of days pulled from a query. What I'm wanting to do is highlight the location on the map with a red color that corresponds to the location containing old inventory.

Examples of each:

[Map_Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpRNa.png)

[Old_Inventory_With_Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSXqM.png)

I attempted to do this using Conditional formatting but couldnt come up with a formula to accomplish this, I also wrote the following code hoping for the same results with no success (running this causes excel to crash):

```
Sub Highlight()

Dim Locations As Range
Dim Old_Inv As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range

Set Locations = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4:CD71")
Set Old_Inv = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C20000")

For Each MyRange In Locations
    For Each MyRange2 In Old_Inv
        If MyRange.Value = MyRange2.Value Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
            End With

        End If

        Next MyRange2
        Next MyRange

End Sub
```

Please note I have very little experience using VBA, sorry if this is way off the mark. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Instead of having nested loops, just loop through your `Locations` range and use the `Match` function (use `WorksheetFunctions` to invoke it) to check if it exists in `Old_Inv`. If `Match` returns a number, change the colour to red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditional formatting:

- Select cell `C4` of your location sheet
- Open Conditional Formatting,
  Manage Rules, New Rule
- Select "Use a formula to determine with cells
  to format" (last option)
- Type the following formula into the box
  "format values where this formula is true" (note that you might have
  to change the formula if you have different language settings)
  `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C4, Sheet2!$C$2:$C$2000,1,FALSE)))`
- Click the format button to select the color you want (on the Fill-tab)
- Press Ok 2 times and enter `=$C$4:$CD$71` in field "Applies to"

Explanation of the formula:

VLOOKUP will search the value of cell C4 (1st parameter) within the given range of Sheet2 (2nd parameter). It returns this value (the 3rd parameter, `1` in the formula tells this) if the exact value is found (the 4th parameter must be `FALSE`).

If the value is not found, excel returns `#NA` which is checked by the surrounding `IsNA`-function. As this would format the cells where the value is *not* in the list, surround the whole stuff with the `NOT`- function which will revert the result.